# What is wrong with this code? Trying to present view as Popoverview from viewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: xcode, ios5

Here's the code. I'm trying to open a specific view as a popover depending upon which row in a TableView was pressed.

```
UIStoryboard *sb;
UIViewController *vc;

// Get a reference to the Storyboard
sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
// Setup the appropriate View Controller
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    // Get the Date
    vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalendarPopupViewController"];
}
if (indexPath.row == 1)
{
    vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StreetAddressViewController"];
}
// Get a reference to the area of the selected row from the Table View
CGRect aFrame = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// Create the popup
UIPopoverController *pc;
pc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];

// Show the Popup
[pc presentPopoverFromRect:aFrame inView:self.view     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

The application terminates with an SIGABRT signal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting a breakpoint on the top and then step downwards until the SIGABRT signal terminates the application? This way you will find exactly which line that causes it.

Comment: Sorry...yes I did that. The final line of code shown is when the app terminates.

Comment: im not able to test it myself at the moment, but is aFrame actually set to a frame? And is self.view an existing view?

Comment: self.view refers to a TableViewController. I believe aFrame is properly initialized through the "rectForRowAtIndex" method.